# The requested PHP extension json and mbstring is missing from your system

Tags: php

I am installing a PHP script in my Cpanel. it's showing an error

> ERROR: The requested PHP extension json is missing from your system.
> ERROR: The requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.

while I have double-checked and enabled these two extensions from my PHP version's what should I do to solve this issue please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Output of phpinfo() to determine whether the Extensions are really active. Depending on your infrastructure a restart of either your webserver and/or the php-fpm may be necessary.